# Blocking Websites by days and hours using Iptables in OpenWRT

Tags: networking, iptables, openwrt

I want to block Facebook the whole day with the exception of the night. I want to implement that in my Linux-based router OpenWRT. The archive I need to modify is /etc/firewall.user (or at least that's what I think) and the command I need to add is something like

`iptables RULE -m time --timestart TIME --timestop TIME --days DAYS -j ACTION`

where rule should be something like the normal rule you use to block facebook or any other website

`iptables -t nat -I INPUT --sport 443 -m string \
                 --string www.facebook.com --algo bm -j REJECT`

but for a reason I continue being able to go to Facebook. Have you got any ideas? Am I writing some commands wrong?. The code I added is:

`iptables -t nat -I INPUT --sport 443 -m string \
                 --string www.facebook.com --algo bm -m time --timestart 1:00 --timestop 20:00 --days Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun -j REJECT`

and it doesn't work ...

Normally for blocking websites I use OpenDNS, but with it I can't allow people going certain hours in the day to Facebook, so using it is not a good option. I would really aprecciate any suggests.
 Thanks in advance and for bothering to read my question

Comment: What about using a web-proxy like squid and disabling routing totally? All hosts in the local network would then need a proxy-setting for web-browsing, but you would be able to easily apply ACLs, even scheduled ones.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably you're trying to use local time clock and kernel, when using `time` module of iptables, assumes that dates and times are given in UTC.

Quoting my `iptables` manual page about `-m time`:

```
   time
       This matches if the packet arrival time/date is within a given range.
       All options are optional, but are ANDed when specified. All times are
       interpreted as UTC by default.
```

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: The easiest way is to specify time in UTC. Take your UTC time offset and substract (or add) so rule will trigger at UTC time, but actually this UTC time will make it trigger at your local time.

Comment: How can I do that in a router with OpenWRT? ... I think I also have another problem, because the command iptables                                                                 " -t nat -I INPUT --sport 443 -m string \
                 --string www.facebook.com --algo bm -j REJECT"                                      doesn't block facebook neither

Comment: OpenWRT router is just a regular Linux as you may noticed. What problem do you experience? Did you determined your time zone and tried specifying time offset? And to debug specific parts of filter you have to remove the part you suspect not working temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a few .sh scripts, that will be executed with crontab.
in crontab :

```
00 9 * * *  /somedir/blockfun.sh
00 18 * * * /somedir/unblockfun.sh
```

and add to blockfun.sh something like this:
`iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "facebook.com" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP` , or how you prefer to block URLs

and of cause delete this rule in unblock.sh

Comment: I'm going to try it with contrab, but the problem (forgetting for one moment about blocking with respect time) is that the command "iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "facebook.com" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP" doesn't block facebook

Comment: upvoting for simplicity. I know more about bash scripts and cron than I do about iptables, even though some of the other solutions seem "more correct"

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are referring to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53196/19575) and [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28851/19575) question when it comes to actually blocking Facebook.

There is two things that aren't discussed there.

1. It's a long shot to assume that every packet heading for Facebook contains the string `www.facebook.com`. Please note, that in the linked questions only the string `facebook.com` is used. Not the strongest of approaches, but this seems the publicly acceptable method of blocking facebook, so you are ok doing that.
2. After resolving the domain name, which your rule does not block, your computer goes ahead and opens a TCP connection to Facebook. The TCP handshake does not contain the string `www.facebook.com` and therefore your rule does not prevent this. After that all, traffic is just accepted by some rule `-m state --state related,established -j ACCEPT` which you are very likely to have.

   The following sceenshot shows my (default) OpenWRT filter table, where you can clearly see, that for any chain, the second rule is the mentioned `related,established` rule. In combination with the successful TCP handshake, your rule is never evaluated for any data traffic to and from Facebook.

   You would have to inject your rule before this generic `-j ACCEPT`.

   [image: OpenWRT INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT chains of the filter table]

Comment: ok, I see what you are saying, but I have already tried with facebook.com and still my network doesn't block it. I don't know very much about networking so it's hard to me to understand you completely (besides the fact I am not an english native speaker). I am going to use crontab as Lev Bystritskiy said, but I can't find any command that can block facebook. What is the explicit command I have to use?

Comment: @Delfin: `cron` is used to schedule (and perform) the execution of programs and scripts. It cannot block Facebook. Therefore deciding to use `cron` or "crontab" is as useful as changing your keyboard layout.  There is no one explicit command that will block Facebook. How you can use iptables to block Facebook depends on your iptables configuration. @gerhard_d. suggested using a proxy server. Maybe that is the better approach for you. I also said the ranking of rules is important not just the string it searches for. I think this is your problem, but without knowing your iptables settings idk.

Comment: Yes, I know that cron is for schedule scripts. What I want is to block facebook only for some hours. So the idea is to use cron to execute a script that blocks facebook in the morning, and after some time, execute a script that unblocks it on the night. But all the iptables commands seem not to work for me, and I don't know how to set that special command depending on my iptables configuration

Comment: @Delfin: You might want to consider sharing your iptables configuration. What it looks like before you try your "special" commands and afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example and some googling I this is what ended up working for me:

```
for website in facebook.com youtube.com; do

iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "$website"  --algo bm  -m time --timestart 00:00 --timestop 17:30 -j REJECT
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 443 -m string --string "$website"  --algo bm  -m time --timestart 00:00 --timestop 17:30 -j REJECT

iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "$website"  --algo bm  -m time --timestart 18:30 --timestop 23:59 -j REJECT
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 443 -m string --string "$website"  --algo bm  -m time --timestart 18:30 --timestop 23:59 -j REJECT

done
```

There were a few problems with what was suggested by @Delfin:

- I had not installed some iptables modules in my openwrt

  opkg update; opkg install iptables-mod-filter
- using *filter instead of *nat otherwise it was complaining: (omitting -t nat puts rules directly in *filter)

> ```
> The "nat" table is not intended for filtering, the use of DROP is therefore inhibited
> ```

- using FORWARD instead of INPUT queue